# OnChange and OnKeyUp on control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an edit box which accepts an email address on my html page.

At the moment, I have a javascript call '`onkeyup`' which verifies if the email address is OK.

And it works well while the user types.

However, if I start typing my address (We will use `me@example.com`), and I start with:

```
me@
```

My autocomplete offers me 'me@example.com', as I have used it before.

When I select that from the autocomplete drop down - '`onkeyup`' doesn't fire. Instead, '`onchange`' fires.

I need both to fire. As the suer types, I want to validate (onkeyup), but I need to also fire the javascript 'onchange'. I don't, however, think I should fire both events. Is there a way to handle both with a single event?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `oninput` event to combine onkeyup and onchange events. This event fires on pasting (ctrl+v) too.

```
<input name="title" oninput="func()">
```

Answer (score 6):

You aren't firing events--the browser is. You're merely listening for them and taking action when they occur.

Rather than having two event-driven functions in your HTML, do one function on either event using proper listeners:

```
$('#myInput').on('keyup change', function() {
    // do validation
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just disable autocomplete `autocomplete="off"` for the input. Browsers react different to autocomplete so unless you want to test the browser beforehand, it is best to just turn off the autocomplete.